# Squared Error Loss for Bayesian estimator of Normal distribution

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, error, posterior

I'm following Brad Efron and Trevor Hastie book "Computer Age Statistical Inference" ([link](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/CASI/order.html)). In chapter 7, they begin to debate the James-Stein estimator by calculating the Bayes rule, or Bayes posterior mean:

\begin{align}
\mu &\sim N(M, A) \\
x|\mu &\sim N(\mu, 1) \\
\mu | x &\sim N(M + B(x-M), B) \\B&= \frac{A}{A+1}.
\end{align}

They state that:

\begin{align} \mathbb E\left[\left(\hat\mu^\textrm{Bayes} - \mu\right)^2\right] &= B \\
\mathbb E\left[\left(\hat\mu^\textrm{MLE} - \mu\right)^2\right] &= 1.
\end{align}

My question is how exactly they calculated the expectation? I think for the MLE it's expectation with regards to $x|\mu,$ then it's simply the variance = 1; but I'm not sure how you get a $B$ in the Bayes case. You do get a $B$ if you take the expectation w.r.t. to $\mu|x.$

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this

Comment: Found it. Posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work it fully out, but it should be with respect to the joint distribution, $f(u,x) = f(x|u)f(u)$ as given by the problem formulation. When unstated, Expectations are typically with respect to the joint of all random variables in the expression. In this context, looking at the text it is clear that this expectation is in the spirit of Bayes Risk which is also an expectation with respect to the joint.

See this [note](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025013810/http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/10-702/week4a.pdf) as an example of a reference for Bayes Risk and its calculation.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I've managed to write down as straight-forward a solution
as I can.

[image: A direct proof of the statement]